# Extended Kalman Filter measurment vs input vector

Tags: kalman-filters, measurement

What is difference between measurement and input vector in Extended Kalman Filter? Isn't always input also measurement? If so how to update input vector if I have acceleration or yawrate as input vector and they aren't constant.

Comment: Are you thinking of something like GPS/IMU integration where the physical model uses the IMU outputs as inputs to the model, and then compares the predicted position with GPS?

Comment: The measurement vector is the input vector in the EKF. Your input vector can be time variant. Then, you just run the filter in a loop that traverses through time.